# Looking For Information about coloring/highlighting output text in python

Tags: python, functions, color

one of the first modules I’m working on in a python program I’m putting together is a journal.

I’m getting comfortable using the print function, but for this project it would be great if i Could differentiate some of the text output from others. For example, here’s a text output sample from the program:

November_29_2017
Log_1 11/29/17-Completed Homework 
Log_2 11/29/17-Did 30min of Cardio

In that sample, November_29_2017 is a printed dictionary label.
What I would like to do is have that output in a different color instead of the standard output color, so that way I can differentiate it as a label or headline in my journal.

I don’t know the exact magnitude of this task, but if I could at least be provided with some research materials, I’d be more than willing and appreciative to get this going. Thank you!

### UPDATE:12/24/2017

Recently I utilized ANSI escape codes to get the color on my print-outs, but this method is limited for me, because it seems to only work with string literals, and not printable objects like list and dictionaries. For example, here is an ANSI escape code to color a string literal:

print '\033[1;34mBlue like Blood\033[1;m'

The output would be the string "Blue like blood" colored blue. But, what if I had a list:

L=["Blue like Blood","Orange bananas and red monkeys."]

Now, it would be time consuming typing all the text in the list object directly into the function and passing it, what would be better is if I could pass the list object through the function using it's index(or key if it's a dict object).

I'm still a rookie in Python, but I believe I know enough that simply trying to slap a list or dict call between an escape code isn't going to work(I tried it).

What I think I need is a method for print() that automatically colors the text of any object passed through the function, like I said, I'm a rookie but I believe it would look something like this:

print.add_color(L[0])

Terms like: Mapping, "create callable objects", classes,etc., I don't get yet but...well I really don't know but I feel like I'm close. Please, still looking for info, and thanks to the people that have provided input.

Comment: You would probably have better luck with this question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Are you printing the output directly to the console or are you writing to a file or GUI window? That makes a world of difference for the possibilities of coloring/highlighting/formatting the output.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I’m printing directly to console. My program is pretty simple at it’s current stage, it can be ran completely from within terminal/command-prompt. I want to see color on some of its output within the terminal. I have been reading about things like Colorama and Colored. I’m about to install the Colored package on to my Pi, see if that can get it done.

Comment: You can likely use the [ANSI color escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors). Try `print("\033[31mHello\033[0m World")` on the target terminal to see if they're supported.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yeah. That’s what I just got done testing. The problem is, some of the strings I want to color belong to list, and I tried hard but I couldn’t figure out how to apply the escape code to list objects, or if it’s even possible. I don’t know if there is a method like print.”something” that I could find or make that would automatically color the output text of objects passed through the print function. Without that, I’m stuck having to type string literals(very long) instead of being able to use list indexes or passing dictionary keys.

Comment: Could you provide some more concrete examples, maybe edit them into the body of you question?  It sounds like you might want to define some `colorize` function that you can then `map` onto lists, call directly, etc.

Comment: *simply trying to slap a list or dict call between an escape code isn't going to work(I tried it)* - sure you can add escape sequences to an object like a  `list`, when you convert your `list` to a string first, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/how-to-convert-list-to-string), or google for "python list to string" to find plenty of sources. Note ANSI escape codes don't work in every environment.

Comment: ... and I recommend you google for some examples how to create formatted output of lists in general, not specifically with colors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400015/python-list-printing-formatting

Comment: @DocBrown Yeah, I get that now. If I’m correct, escape codes only work with strings right? What I didn’t understand that the escape codes don’t work on objects like list and dictionaries, but will work strings between escape codes, which can be stored in list or dictionaries. I didn’t get the gap between strings GUI elements. I believe that once you move pass the desire of wanting to color objects outside of strings, you are probably moving into GUI territory. Not an expert at any of this stuff yet, but that’s my analysis.

Comment: Another thing that threw me off was the fact that I was initially using the escape codes with strings and running my script in python IDLE, which I didn’t realize does not support the escape codes. I have been running the script in terminal, and with the exception of one code I tried, it has been working fine.

Comment: @IamPyre: the console you are using can only display characters. So to display something like a list, it has to be converted to a stream of characters first. I think you got confused by the fact `print` converts non-string objects automatically to a default string representation. But as soon as this default representation is not sufficient any more, you need to implement your formatting functions, that is pretty normal.

Comment: @IamPyre: moreover, a direct combination of an "escape code" (which is a string itself) with a list does not make sense for the same reasons you cannot concatenate a string with a number in python like `"123" + 456`. In this example, you will either have to convert the number  to a string `"123" + str(456)`, or the string to a number `int(123) + 456` to make this operation meaningful.

Comment: @DocBrown I don’t believe that’s the problem I described. What I’m trying to say is that I thought that escape codes worked with list and dictionary literals, meaning that I thought I could use keys or indexes to reference a value: print(‘escape-code’\list[0]\’escape-code’).            I know now that it doesn’t work like that, I have to actually add the escape code to the object within the list, and then use print function. Like I said, I’m a rookie. Thanks for your feedback by the way.

Comment: @IamPyre: when you write a line like `print(‘escape-code’\list[0]\’escape-code’)`, the python interpreter first has to evaluate `‘escape-code’\list[0]\’escape-code’`, so you are trying to combine a string (`‘escape-code’`) with a list directly. And that makes no sense, you are trying to combine two values of different, incompatible types. And that is *exactly* what the example I gave above is about.

Comment: ... FWIW  `print(‘escape-code’ + str(list[0]) + ’escape-code’)` is the most simple way I can think of to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

> Recently I utilized ANSI escape codes to get the color on my print-outs, but this method is limited for me, because it seems to only work with string literals, and not printable objects like list and dictionaries.

The comments you gave indicated you simply got the syntax wrong. Try a function like this one:

```
def blueprint(x):
    print('\033[34m' + str(x) + '\033[0m')
```

(The parentheses for `print` are necessary in Python 3, and optional in Python 2).

Applying this to your example

```
 L=["Blue like Blood","Orange bananas and red monkeys."]
 blueprint(L)
```

should do the trick, you can actually pass everything into that function which can be converted to a string by `str`.

Note this will only work in a terminal window which supports ANSI color codes. Under Linux or Mac, this should not be a problem, as well as in a Windows 10 environment, and for earlier Windows versions, the Colorama module (thanks to @tale852150 for the link) should solve this in a platform-independent manner.

As to your original problem: creating a journal which will only display correctly when printed out in an ANSI terminal is IMHO a very limited approach. If you ever try to save your journal to a file, and then open it in a text editor, you will only see escape sequences and none of the colors. A more standard way of doing these things today is utilizing HTML, writing your journal to an HTML file and use a web browser for displaying it. That way, you could mark headlines using the [`<head>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_head.asp), and format them with any color you like using [cascading style sheets](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try [Colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama). This may be what you are looking for and it works on Windows.

Here is some example code:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

Here is an example with a list:

[image: Color text in Python list]

To install colorama on RHEL:

```
pip install colorama
```

Also this example right here in SO:

[Print to terminal in colors with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors)

Comment: This is probably helpful for the OP, but still far away from a good answer.

Comment: @DocBrown - appreciate the feedback. How can I make it better?

Comment: Well, the OP explicitly asked about how to colorize a list or a dict. A short example how to do this would probably answer that main part of the question.

Comment: That is not an example how to colorize a list or a dict. Did you read the question thoroughly?

Comment: @DocBrown  - I wanted to give a general example.  Then an example with a list.

Comment: That is - obviously - still not addressing the OPs problems.

Comment: @DocBrown So OP wants a method called add_color which is passed a list and a color?  His method signature does not pass a color, just a list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71092/discussion-between-tale852150-and-doc-brown).